# limited amount of instances on creation on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I`m trying to run the maximum amount of instances on ec2 with the following parameters:

```
    AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey,secretKey);
    AmazonEC2Client ec2 = new AmazonEC2Client(credentials);
    RunInstancesRequest request = new RunInstancesRequest();

    request.setInstanceType(InstanceType.T2Micro.toString());
            request.setMinCount(1);
            request.setMaxCount(20);
            request.setImageId("ami-b73b63a0");
            request.setKeyName("hardwell");
            request.setUserData(getUserDataScript());
            ec2.runInstances(request);
```

But only the first one is launched, when I`m trying to run this code for the second time I get this error:

```
Your quota allows for 0 more running instance(s). You requested at least 1
```

But the maximum amount is 20. What`s the explanation for that?

Thanks.

Comment: The quota includes the current number of running instances. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14241609/api-for-checking-ec2-instance-limit

Comment: I don`t understand, what should I change to launch more then 1?

Comment: This code should start 20 instances the first time you run it.  Have you confirmed that it only launches 1, and that the 1 is really a t2.micro, and that you have no other instances running in the region?

Comment: There is a default limit of 20 concurrently running EC2 instances. There are also limits on specific instance types. You can view these limits by clicking the **Limits** link in the Amazon EC2 management console. How many instances (in total) are currently running in your account in the same region (before issuing this command)?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have exhausted your limits for Max EC2 instances

To know more check 2 things on AWS Console

1. Go to the **EC2 Dashboard**. It will show you the count if total running instances
2. Click on Go to the **Limits** link and see what your account limits are. If you have not got this increased for your account, this will be 20.

Subtract the running count from the limits and you will know how many more instances you can run